# PHP error can not retrieve LIKE statements from android application

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql-like

I am trying to search up the database with an android application, but when I search for a string element with the SQL syntaxes 'LIKE',

such as:

```
SELECT * FROM `test123` WHERE (`name` LIKE '%A%')
```

it would give me an error:

> A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 of ....

but if I search for:

```
SELECT * FROM `test123`
```

it'll work fine.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("website.com","root","password");
mysql_select_db("test123");

$q=mysql_query($_REQUEST['sql']);
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: I sincerely hope `mysql_query($_REQUEST['sql'])` is only for testing purposes...

Comment: @user870077 Can you include some code from your Android application side. I'm pretty sure the problem is there.

Answer (score 3):

```
$output = array();
while ($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $output[] = $e;
}
```

The problem may simply be that if there are no results, `$output` is never defined. When you then try to `json_encode($output)`, PHP throws a warning about `$output` being undefined, which leads to final output like:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: output in ...
null
```

Which is invalid JSON. Even if your warnings are suppressed, the output will just be `null`, which is not a JSON array. If your client expects an array, then it will be disappointed by `null`.

**Always initialize your variables.**

Answer (score 0):

It should be just

```
"SELECT * FROM test123 WHERE name LIKE '%A%'"
```

Comment: But this will only work if the query returns at least 1 row. The OP's code still has one more fundamental flaw; It returns malformed JSON when no rows are returned from the query.

Answer (score 0):

i think this can be work fine    SELECT * FROM `test123`(`name`) WHERE (`name` LIKE '%A%')

Answer (score 0):

When I user `php json_encode` it always returns a `JSONObject`, not a `JSONArray`.  Try printing your raw result to Logcat and see what form it's in.

Comment: `json_encode` will return an object when you give it an object or an associative array. An array with numeric keys will return an array. Calling `json_encode` with the option `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` will always return an object.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - I always use an associative array, so that makes sense.